# VNC single click and UAC on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vnc, uac, remote-assistance, ultravnc

I work for an IT consulting company and we have been using [UltraVNC Single Click](http://www.uvnc.com/addons/singleclick.html) to remote in to our users' desktops.  It has been working really well and our techs have been very satisfied with this solution.  However....  Our clients are finally moving from XP to Windows 7.  They will not have admin rights.  We will not be providing them with admin passwords.  Starting up the single-click executable generates a VNC prompt on the remote desktop.  This is a non-starter for us.

The whole point of using SC is that we can view the user's desktop and that they do not need to have some kind of service constantly running and listening for connection requests, so standard VNC or RDP will not work for us.

Has anyone dealt with single click in Vista/Windows 7?  What workarounds did you employ?  Maybe there is a method I haven't found to white list a given application so that it does not generate UAC prompts?

Edit:  To clarify, disabling UAC IS NOT AN OPTION.  I need to work around UAC for this one application, but leave it enabled.

Answer (score 3):

i use a ruby script, packed into an exe with ocra.
since it's not regonized as a self extracted zip, 
windows seven does not prompt for admin password.
may sounds complicate, but it is not.

it's realy a good workaround.

plus you can generate yourself your own exe and change setting offline.

.

**how to :**

make dir

```
myexe
```

unzip ultravnc-sc.exe into

```
myexe/ultravnc-sc
```

install ruby : http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ (i use 1.8.x branch)

install ocra : on a command line

```
gem install ocra -r  --http-proxy=http://yourproxy_ifneed
```

edit ruby script myexe/myexe.rbw :

```
Dir.chdir File.dirname($0)
exit if defined?(Ocra)
system('ultravnc-sc/winvnc.exe')
```

build exe : on a command line

```
cd myexe
ocra --icon ultravnc-sc/icon1.ico myexe.rbw ultravnc-sc/**
```

test it !

that's all!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ChuckVNC](http://www.chunkvnc.com/), there InstantSupport executable runs as the current user.

However, you will not be able to perform any actions which require Administrator privileges, the UAC prompt will still appear.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem.  One work around is the use 7-Zip to extract the custom "ultravnc-sc.exe" you made to a directory, "ultravnc-sc", and then run the "winvnc.exe" inside of it.

If your users to not have 7-Zip installed or another program that can extract a self extracting executable, you can simply extract it yourself, and then create a ZIP archive of the "ultravnc-sc" directory for the user to download; e.g. "ultravnc-sc.zip". Have the user download, "ultravnc-sc.zip", extract it and run "winvnc.exe".  It's not as easy as one click to run, but it's not too hard to walk them through extracting a Zip over the phone.

Also, ChuckVNC appears to be the direction things are headed now, but requires a repeater running for it to function.

Answer (score -3):

You can disable the UAC IN VISTA OR 7 by  Launching MSCONFIG by from the Run menu.
Click on the Tools tab. Scroll down till you find "Disable UAC" Click on that line.

Comment: I don't think the goal is to disable UAC entirely (and I don't think that would solve the problem, since the users are not Administrators).

Comment: coneslayer is correct.  Giving the users admin rights would defeat the purpose